# TypeError: "name function" is not a function

Tags: angulajs

Estoy llamando a dos acciones dentro de la misma funcion que acciona un boton.
La primera accion es exitosa, pero en la segunda no encuentro la falla. me lanza un error **"TypeError: "name function" is not a function"**. Busque y busque y no encuentro manera de resolver este problema: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas abajo dejo codigo de mi boton y mi funcion con sus dos acciones:::
(NOTA: Cabe reecalcar que mi boton esta en un ng-repeat.

```
<td style="padding-left:20px" ng-repeat="item in recomList |limitTo:limit:start"> 
  <button type="button" id="recomendacionID" value="{{item.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="btnAceptarRecomendacion()"> Seleccionar</button></td>
```

::Aqui mi funcion que acciona el boton::

```
$scope.btnAceptarRecomendacion = function(){
                 console.log('Entro a boton Aceptar::');
                 $scope.idRecomendacion=j$('#recomendacionID').val();
                 console.log('Id de Recomendacion Aceptada:: ', $scope.idRecomendacion);
                 console.log('Id de Oportunidad:: ', $scope.oppId);
                 console.log('Id de perfilCliente:: ', $scope.idPC);
                 
                 if( $scope.idcsp!=null){
                        console.log('Id CotSitioPlan:: ', $scope.idcsp);
                  }else{
                         console.log('!Aun no hay cotSitioPlan!');
                  }
                                         
                      
                 if($scope.idcsp!=null&&$scope.idcsp!=undefined&&$scope.idcsp!=''){
                         console.log('Entro a clonar cotizacion::');
                         RecomendacionesPC_CTRL.clonarCotizacion($scope.idRecomendacion,$scope.idPC,$scope.oppId, $scope.idcsp, function(){
                         $scope.$apply();
                         
                     });
                     
                  }else{
                          console.log('Entro a plan modelado de recomendacion::');
                          RecomendacionesPC_CTRL.aceppRecom($scope.idRecomendacion,$scope.idPC,$scope.oppId, $scope.idcsp, function(){
                          $scope.$apply();
                             
                         });
                     
                     }
               }
```

El IF de la accion: 'Entro a plan modelado de recomendacion::' , Me la ejecuta con exito, pero cuando la validacion apunta a  'Entro a clonar cotizacion::', me sale el error en consola: **TypeError: "name function" is not a function.** Necesito de su ayuda, porfavor

Comment: De donde viene `RecomendacionesPC_CTRL`

Comment: Estoy en Salesforce, es un CRM en la empresa, una visualForce es como un HTML, en donde uso codigo tal cual una pagina web.
 en esta parte el resultado de la funcion va a realizar acciones al codigo de la clase

Comment: Es como una accion JAVA. Pasandole parametros, que en este caso el metodo necesita, los cuales son:
**($scope.idRecomendacion,$scope.idPC,$scope.oppId, $scope.idcsp)**

Comment: Es que el error hace referencia a ese método `clonarCotizacion`, puede estar pasando algo al momento en tu aplicación quiere utilizar ese módulo, websocket o etc.

Comment: Si asi es amigo, cuando la validacion apunta a: "clonarCotizacion" es cuando me lanza ese error. Cuando la validacion apunta al else, en el cual el nombre es: "aceppRecom", no tienen ningun problema